# How do I run tests in Play Framework that depend on having a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, playframework-2.0

I'm working on a web application using Java Play Framework 2.0 that heavily relies on databases. I want to start writing functional tests for it that will need to access a database that has data in it already, but I don't want it to touch the database for the actual application, and I want the test database to be reset between tests. How could I set this up and access it for a Play application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never worked with Java Play, but the concept of database testing is commonly known across all kinds of languages. From my point of view, there are three solutions to use

1. Create a separate database, that is not in production and let your tests run against that database. The pro is definitely, that you are testing your code against real data. The con is to import fresh data once in a while and keep track of schema changes
2. You could import a clean database with just structure and some predefined figures, that will be reset before each test suite/case
3. The most preferable way is to use Mockup objets. That only works under the assumption, that you are using a ORM framework, so that you can capsulate.

**Some links for further research**

http://mockrunner.sourceforge.net (mocking supported for jdbc)

http://code.google.com/p/mockito/ (for general mocking)

Answer (score 0):

If the database does not have to be MySQL then I suggest using an in memory database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). It's great for testing purposes and spins up very quickly. Also, with an in memory database you don't have to worry about cleaning up test side effects (new DB for each test). This also has the advantage that the tests are self contained and some one else testing your code (or even a build/automation server) does not need to install MySQL either.

If you *must* use MySQL as the database then it would be possible to script @Before/@After hooks that setup your schema and initialize any data you need but if it can be avoided I'd suggest going the in memory route.